# ubuntu: file browser as root?

Tags: ubuntu, browser

Is it possible to run "`File Browser`" as root on the latest version of Ubuntu (`Jaunty`)?

I'd like to create a `launcher` (shortcut) to run `File Browser` this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an application launcher that calls

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Comment: What is an application launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can specify the path to open in the File Browser. For example '/usr/share/java':

```
gksu nautilus /usr/share/java
```